# How to point GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_CREDENTIALS environment variable in a VueFire project?

Tags: firebase, environment-variables, nuxtjs3, firebase-tools, vuefire

I was trying to run a VueFire project. The docs mentioned that I should use a service account. So I downloaded one and put it in my project folder, added it to `.gitignore` and point an environment variable to it:

```
# My .env file
GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_CREDENTIALS=service-account.json
```

I tried running it using Firebase emulator, and I got the following warning:

> Failed to parse service account json file: Error: Service account object must contain a string "project_id" property.

When I checked my terminal, I see the following warning popping up when emulator is starting up:

```
functions: Your GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable points to /home/starleaf1/.config/firebase/starleaf1_gmail_com_application_default_credentials.json. Non-emulated services will access production using these credentials. Be careful!
```

It looks like the emulator ignores the `.env` and looks for the service account file somewhere else. Is there a way to resolve this?

I have also tried:

- Setting the env value to absolute path, i.e: `/home/starleaf1/service-account.json`, but it still doesn't work.
- Naming the file `.env.local` or `.env.development`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, I already have a `GOOGLE_CLOUD_CREDENTIALS` in my environment variables. A `.env` file will *not* override already-existing variables. To point it to the correct file, execute this before starting Firebase Emulator Suite:

```bash
export GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_CREDENTIALS=service-account.json
```

When building for production, Nuxt will take into the `.env` build.

Comment: I've been struggling to find out why npm run dev didn't works.
Turns out, npm run build works..

Thanks for the explanation..